# Constructor method can't access nested properties of a child object in a for loop

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor

```
function myConstructor (arg) {
    this.myName = arg;
    this.totalNumber = 0;
    this.foo = {
        bar: {
            someBoolean: false,
            someNumber: 5
        },
        baz: {
            someBoolean: false,
            someNumber: 10
        }
    };
}

myConstructor.prototype.getNumber = function () {
    console.log(this); //successfully returns the child object

    for (var i in this.foo) {
        //console log tests
        console.log(this); //still returns the child object with all properties, including the myName 'whatever'
        console.log(this.foo); //returns the 'foo' object with all nested properties
        console.log(i); //returns 'bar' and 'baz', respectively
        console.log(this.foo.hasOwnProperty(i)); //returns true

        //where it all goes wrong
        console.log(typeof(i)); //returns 'string'
        console.log(this.foo.i); //returns undefined, even though 'this.foo' definitely has 'bar' and 'baz' properties

        //what I'm trying to accomplish
        /*
        if (this.foo.i.hasOwnProperty('someBoolean') && this.foo.i.someBoolean === true) {
            this.totalNumber += this.foo.i.someNumber;
        } //returns 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
        */
    }
    return this.totalNumber;
};

var myChild = new myConstructor('whatever');
myChild.getNumber();
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is using a constructor to create a child. The having nested objects inside that child, with various properties that I will change later in my code. Then using a method of the constructor to access data within the nested objects of that child. Everything works until I get two-deep in nested objects.

I've tried passing every variable, object and property around with various "var this == that"s and "var prop == i"s and etc. Nothing I do seems to work.

Comment: foo does not have a property called i. it should be this.foo[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` has no property named `i`.

You want `foo[i]`, to get the property with that name.

Comment: This works, but I'm confused. Why does `foo.hasOwnProperty(i)` return true? I thought that `obj.prop` and `obj['prop']` were the same.

Comment: Wait... I think I get it. it's literally looking for "foo.i", instead of the variable that "i" represents, so bracket notation is needed to call the variable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Danneh: Yes, but `i` is not the same as `'i'`.

Answer (score 0):

it should be  console.log(this.foo[i])

As foo doen not contain "i" property.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion lies in the way that for-each/for-in loops are normally used in other programming languages such as Java, C#. Here's the difference:

```
// java
for(int x in list)
    x = x+1;

// javascript
var x;
for(x in list)
    list[x] = list[x] + 1;
```